# What's the role of ReLU units in Convolutional neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

In convolutional neural net architectures, I found many Convolutional layers stacked with ReLU layers. What is its purpose? Why would we want to threshold the output of the convolutional layer since it's basically a representation of the input image.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt edited the question