# Why are nonlinear activations used in convolutional neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution

Isn't convolution non-linear already?  Do we need a nonlinearity in a different layer as as well?  I understand the reasons why ReLU is good cited [in this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/226927/163572), but is there an intuitive reason we need nonlinear activation functions for CNNs?

### Ways I've tried to answer this question:

1. How CNNs work? [Stanford cs231](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks).
2. In the paper [Striving for Simplicity: The All Convolutional Net](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6806), Springenberg et al. suggest that pooling is bad and that we should strive for an all-convolutional neural net. Geoffrey Hinton also claims [pooling is bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTawFwUvnLE&t=2442s). Admittedly, I should read the paper more thoroughly. If I come up with a simple explanation after reading it, I'll post an answer.
3. [Why do we use ReLU in neural networks and how do we use it?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226923/why-do-we-use-relu-in-neural-networks-and-how-do-we-use-it)
4. [What's the role of ReLU units in Convolutional neural networks?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256237/whats-the-role-of-relu-units-in-convolutional-neural-networks?noredirect=1&lq=1) This question got closed for some reason, not sure why.  It was a different question than the question they claimed was duplicate.
5. [Why must a nonlinear activation function be used in a backpropagation neural network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782071/why-must-a-nonlinear-activation-function-be-used-in-a-backpropagation-neural-net)

Answer (score 5):

Given the weight matrix, the convolution is a linear operator. If $x$ and $y$ are image vectors, and $W$ is the weight matrix, then it is easy to verify that

$f(x+y;W)$ = $f(x;W) + f(y;W)$  --> (intuition is that I can either convolve over 2 different images and then add them, or vice versa)

and

$f(ax;W) = af(x;W)$ --> (intuition is that if I amplify each pixel in the image by a factor, then the entire convolution will be amplified by that factor)

Comment: However, most CNNs also apply maxpooling, which is non-linear. Why would activation functions be necessary in this case? I can imagine that immediately stacked convlayers, for example in a residual unit, can benefit from activations to add non-linearity and not just the visible range. But consider a relu and maxpooling, why add the relu that can only kill neurons, when you already can get an elbow from the maxpool?